# Problem with sphinx search when searching by second word in phrase

Tags: sphinx

I have a sphinx index set up with a field that has the following data:

```
James Smith
```

When I search for 'James' or 'James Smi', it will return the proper result, but when I search for 'James S' it doesn't return anything.

I also have a real time index (RT) and it has the same data in it and I'm able to search for 'James S' and it returns the proper result.

Here is what I have in my config file for the main index

```
min_word_len            = 1
html_strip              = 0
min_infix_len           = 2
expand_keywords   = 1
min_prefix_len    = 1
index_exact_words = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Min_infix_len=2 means part word matches are only going to work for two letter queries or longer. The j does not match in part of word, only a standalone word. Because of min_word_len

Comment: There must be some way to work around this. i.e. storing the search text as something different or maybe stripping the space out and then searching (but indexing without the space as well)

Comment: Well in theory just setting `min_infix_len = 1` would allow it work, but remember sphinx doesn't like it too short, maybe it won't let you use 1. Yes, storing as one word (without space - or maybe replace space with _ ) shoudl work. But single words are limited to 42 chars IIRC